# Codeigniter MySQL Group Results into MultiDimensional Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Not sure on the best wording for the question (hence not able to search for what I am trying to achieve very well), but here is what I am trying to achieve:

I can extract a set of results from a table like this:

```
$this->db->select('sets.id,
                   sets.wo_id,
                   sets.weight,
                   sets.reps,
                   exercise_list.title');
$this->db->from('sets');
$this->db->join('exercise_list','sets.ex_id= exercise_list.id');
$this->db->where('sets.wo_id',$wo_id);
//return $query->result_array();
$q = $this->db->get();
$query = $q->result_array();
return $query;
```

Without worrying too much about what that is doing, it returns me an array (only showing the bits I use) like this:

```
******************************
* title  *  weight  *  reps  *
******************************
* exer1  *  25      *   6    *
* exer1  *  25      *   5    *
* exer1  *  25      *   5    *
* exer3  *  80      *   7    *
* exer3  *  80      *   7    *
* exer3  *  80      *   6    *
******************************
```

What I currently do is just foreach loop thru this table to present them:

```
<?php foreach($sets as $set): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $set['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $set['weight']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $set['reps']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which renders, very similarly to the mysql array showin above.

BUT what I want to achieve is something more like this (example only):

```
<div (for example)> 
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><?php echo $title; ?></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Set No.</th><th>Weight</th><th>Reps</th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th><th> 25 </th><th> 6 </th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th><th> 25 </th><th> 5 </th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th><th> 25 </th><th> 5 </th>
    <tr>
</div>

<div (for example)> 
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><?php echo $NextTitle; ?></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Set No.</th><th>Weight</th><th>Reps</th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th><th> 80 </th><th> 7 </th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th><th> 80 </th><th> 7 </th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th> 1 </th><th> 80 </th><th> 6 </th>
    <tr>
</div>
```

So it renders something like this:

```
***************************
*         Exer1           *
***************************
* Set No. * Weight * Reps *
***************************
*    1    *   25   *  6   *
*    2    *   25   *  5   *
*    3    *   25   *  5   *
***************************

***************************
*         Exer2           *
***************************
* Set No. * Weight * Reps *
***************************
*    1    *   80   *  7   *
*    2    *   80   *  7   *
*    3    *   80   *  6   *
***************************
```

Sorry this is such a long post, hopefully its clear what I am trying to do. I think it is something along the lines of as I get the data out of mysql, iterate through it row by row and add it to sub-arrays per exer*.

So I should get an array something like this:

```
array
(
  exer1
  (
    array(25,6), array(25,5), array(25,5)
  )
  exer2
  (
    array(80,7), array(80,6), array(80,6)
  )
)
```

Gosh, hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of solving this. If you want a pure php-way of solving it, without changing your MySQL code, you can just:

```
$title = "";
$i = 1;
<?php foreach($sets as $set):
    if($title != $set['title']){
         $i = 1;
         if($title != "") { echo "</div>";}?>
         <div> 
         <tr>
             <td colspan="3"><?php echo $set['title']; ?></td>
         <tr>
         <tr>
             <th>Set No.</th><th>Weight</th><th>Reps</th>
         <tr>
         <tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; $i++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $set['weight']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $set['reps']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $title = $set['title'];
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks. This is much better than over complicating it like I thought I was going to have to do with my MySQL statements.